# How to rename observations with semi-consistent format?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm working with the following data frame:

```
Team       Direction      Side
Joe         HB-L           L
Eric        HB-R           R
Tim         FB-L           R
Mike        HB             L
```

I would like to eliminate the "HB" or "FB" preceding the "L" or "R" in the 'Direction' column. I would also like to eliminate the observations for which there is no "L" or "R" in the 'Direction' column. I would like it to look like this:

```
Team       Direction      Side
Joe         L              L
Eric        R              R
Tim         L              R
```

Then, I want to add a column that indicates if the 'Direction' and 'Side' columns are the same. If yes, I would like it to read 'NEAR', if not I would like it to read "FAR."

```
Team       Direction      Side     Relation
Joe         L              L        NEAR
Eric        R              R        NEAR
Tim         L              R        FAR
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in `base R` with `sub` to remove the substring till the `-` after subsettng the rows based on the presence of `-` in 'Direction

```
df1 <- subset(df1, grepl('-', Direction))
df1$Direction <- sub(".*-", "",  df1$Direction)
```

-output

```
df1
#  Team Direction Side
#1  Joe         L    L
#2 Eric         R    R
#3  Tim         L    R
```

Then, we can use `==` to create a logical condition to replace the valuess to 'FAR', 'NEAR'

```
df1$Relation <- with(df1, c('FAR', 'NEAR')[(Direction == Side) + 1])
```

-output

```
df1
#  Team Direction Side Relation
#1  Joe         L    L     NEAR
#2 Eric         R    R     NEAR
#3  Tim         L    R      FAR
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
     filter(grepl('-', Direction)) %>% 
     mutate(Direction = str_replace(Direction, '.*-', ''), 
        Relation = case_when(Direction == Side ~ 'NEAR', TRUE ~ 'FAR'))
#   Team Direction Side Relation
#1  Joe         L    L     NEAR
#2 Eric         R    R     NEAR
#3  Tim         L    R      FAR
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df1)[grepl('-', Direction)][, Direction := trimws(Direction,
     whitespace = '.*-')][, Relation := fifelse(Direction == Side, 'NEAR', 'FAR')][]
#   Team Direction Side Relation
#1:  Joe         L    L     NEAR
#2: Eric         R    R     NEAR
#3:  Tim         L    R      FAR
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Team = c("Joe", "Eric", "Tim", "Mike"), Direction = c("HB-L", 
"HB-R", "FB-L", "HB"), Side = c("L", "R", "R", "L")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can first `filter` the rows that have `"-"` in them , remove everything until `"-"` and with `if_else` assign `'NEAR'` OR `'FAR'` value to `Relation`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  filter(str_detect(Direction, '-')) %>%
  mutate(Direction = str_remove(Direction, '.*-'), 
         Relation = if_else(Direction == Side, 'NEAR', 'FAR'))

#  Team Direction Side Relation
#1  Joe         L    L     NEAR
#2 Eric         R    R     NEAR
#3  Tim         L    R      FAR
```